# Debunk: tripping KNOX removes your battery life?

Tags: rooting, samsung

## UPDATE 04/21/2020

Great news for people struggling with battery issues on these phones.  I used a non-root APP called "Repair Battery Life", and it actually fixed my rapid battery drain issue!  It identified some cells that were somehow not working and fixed them.  I did some tests to see if restarting the phone would cause the cells to fault out again, and restarting did not cause that to happen; so, I went so far as to reformat the phones.  Reformatting the phones seems to re-create the battery issues.  I don't know why, but I've tested this on S8+ Korean and S8 Hong Kong, and I get the same issues (seems like the same battery cells) that are resolved by this app and don't recur (so far) without reformat).

I feel a bit nervous to post this because I don't hope Samsung finds a new way to hurt users who root their phones, but it's such an important discovery, I really hope someone can explain why/what might be happening that this software solves a very serious problem.  My battery life is up by hours!

## ORIGINAL ASKED

I've heard various people in XDA reporting that rooting a Samsung S8 (or similar--S8+, S7, S7 Edge, S6, S5, S9, etc.) will remove 30% of your battery life, permanently.

Is there any truth to this?  I think the myth is built on reports that KNOX *uses* 30% of the battery life in some phones and removing it will *increase* battery life by 30%, but I have no way to preverify that.

My experience is that a damaged Samsung phone will lose a lot of its battery life.  Maybe damaging it trips Knox?

Comment: Update: I have spoken with a few second-hand sellers now who have universally told me that the battery life is significantly reduced in rooted phones.

Comment: power consuming depends on display and cpu usage, which is controlled by several settings and kernel (and you). if a ROM is rooted or custom ROM installed this opens availbility to control parameters. influences is possible in both directions depending on cleverness of the developer. even simple OTA on stock ROM can change power consuming - which have impact to battery life

Comment: @alecxs it's an interesting blurb, but it only whets my curiosity further to know how, specifically, tripping knox might lead to a reduction in battery life.  I noticed when my phone was damaged an immediate huge reduction in battery life which did not cease when I replaced the battery and the faulty antenna.  Eventually, the phone broke, and the phone is not off-warranty; so, I tend to believe the cause is the damage.  I do wonder if something related occurred due to the impact, though, and if similar reductions are seen immediately after knox is tripped.  In fact, I plan to test it, myself.

Comment: i can not see any relationship between physical damage and knox

Comment: My thinking is that the phone's being damaged may have inadvertently broken the efuse or triggered something that broke the efuse, and the result of the fuse being severed is a change in the way energy moves about the phone: "...a reverse engineer by the name of Speedy22 theorized that Microsoft could actually blow the CPU's eFuses in such a way that "it may be possible to shut power off to the CPU permanently or increase the core supply to the point of self-destruct."  The warranty is not void 0x0.

Comment: knox is a encryption container. tripping knox means nothing more than erasing all data and permanently disable this security feature https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o08PJj-LfKs

Comment: Regarding the latest revision about "Repair Battery Life" app, [are you sure?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/128329/44325)

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes.  I'm sure.  I've tested this on three phones, now, and two of them have had very substantial battery increases.  I haven't used a high-precision timer to see how the battery life has changed, but I do gauge my battery life based on games played.  The difference is very noticeable, as if the battery life has doubled.  The batteries would usually drain to 85% within a few minutes of unplugging them, which I found very irritating.  I would play 2-3 games before getting the 15% battery warnings.  Now, after using the app, I don't have the rapid 15% loss and am at 50% after 3 games.

Comment: @AndrewT. As far as the third phone, it has a broken screen, and the phone isn't really used.  I've noticed that the initial rapid 15% loss isn't happening, but I haven't done any gaming on that phone.  I hope to do more investigating over time and will update as time goes on.  If you have any requests, please let me know, and I will do my best to comply with whatever steps you hope to see in an attempt to uncover more info!  Thank you!